# Apply VlLOOKUP till last non-empty row in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup, importrange

I have an automatically expanding google in which I am applying a Vlookup formula to extract values from another sheet matching the values from the main sheet.

This is the Vlookup formula-

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, IMPORTRANGE("1MNRMKGkC-c0COugUWpXOe5OxJXfmdXGboxAPhf5SaLA", "Sheet1!B3:E420"),4,0)
```

I want the formula to be auto applied to the new entries which get auto added in the main sheet. I used this formula I found on a website to apply this formula to the whole column also taking care of any empty cells in between.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A), "", VLOOKUP(A2:A, IMPORTRANGE("1MNRMKGkC-c0COugUWpXOe5OxJXfmdXGboxAPhf5SaLA", "Sheet1!B3:E420"),4,0)))
```

My problem is that after using this formula when a new entry is auto added to column A in the sheet, it gets added to 1001th row instead of the next non-empty row, because this formula is being applied to whole column.

Is there some way to apply the Vlookup to just be applied till last non-empty row, so that my next automatic entry gets added in the next empty row? Or any other alternative solution? 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),,VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 IMPORTRANGE("1MNRMKGkC-c0COugUWpXOe5OxJXfmdXGboxAPhf5SaLA", "Sheet1!B3:E420"), 4, 0)), 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That E column is for the 2nd sheet which Vlookup is using to extract data, and it has 420 rows, that's why its E420 there. The problem is with main sheet, A column

Comment: It gives an error saying "Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 5 arguments"

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't have sheet for reference assuming new data is added to new column.

Try this fromula `=ARRAYFORMULA(If(A2:A="","",VLOOKUP(A2:A, IMPORTRANGE("1MNRMKGkC-c0COugUWpXOe5OxJXfmdXGboxAPhf5SaLA", "Sheet1!B3:E420"),4,0)))`

This will do vlookup once there is new data in Column 'A'